# Total, valid, invalid, and pending flag counts in flagging summary

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

I would like to have a count of the total, valid, invalid, and pending flag counts in the flagging summary at `<SE site>/users/flag-weight/<userid>` similar to the following:

> Flags issued: 25 total, 23 valid, 1 invalid, 1 pending

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flag weight audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/flag-weight-audit)

Comment: The intent of this feature is to have at-a-glance information about your overall flagging and to determine if there are any "bad calls" or pending flags.  I disagree with the part of the answer on "Flag weight audit" that it won't "provide true additional benefit".

Comment: related. Posting this because the answer in this post has lot of info - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85141/flag-weight-summary-does-not-say-if-my-flag-was-correct-or-wrong

Comment: Looks like this has been implemented.